# Should all association references be pluralized in the where clauses?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm upgrading a Rails 3 application to a Rails 7 application.  A lot of things that worked in Rails 3 (Ruby 1.9.3) just aren't going to work in Rails 7 (Ruby 3.2.2).  Though I'm confused on this behaviour from the join statement in conjunction with a where clause

When running this query:

```
Request.joins(job: :quote).to_sql
```

I get the response

```
 "SELECT "requests".* FROM "requests"
 INNER JOIN "jobs" ON "jobs"."id" = "requests"."job_id"
 INNER JOIN "quotes" ON "quotes"."job_id" = "jobs"."id""
```

Which makes sense, a simple join.  The confusing part comes when I attempt to use these associations inside of a where clause, like this:

```
Request.joins(job: :quote).where(job: {quote: {attachment_updated_at: nil}}).to_sql
```

which gives me:

```
"SELECT "requests".* FROM "requests"
INNER JOIN "jobs" "job" ON "job"."id" = "requests"."job_id"
INNER JOIN "quotes" ON "quotes"."job_id" = "job"."id"
WHERE "quote"."attachment_updated_at" IS NULL"
```

Trying to utilize the expected object result of this query with:

```
 Request.joins(job: :quote).where(job: {quote: {attachment_updated_at: nil}}).pluck(:id)
```

gives me:

```
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "quote"
```

Which is expected because `quote` is not declared in the select statement.  **Why is the `where` clause changing the `join` statement?** See the difference between `JOIN "jobs" "job"` in the two queries.

#### Fixes

A simple fix to this would be to rename `quote` to `quotes` in the where clause. but that seems really hacky (I'm not looking for quotes, I'm looking for a singular quote) and it's almost like I'm just doing the whole nested query thing wrong.  **Should all association references be pluralized in the where clauses?**

Comment: `joins` works on the associations defined in your model. That means when the association is a `has_one` or `belongs_to` which usually a singular names, then use the singular name in the `joins`. Whereas `where` works on table names, therefore `where` expects pluralized names all the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails uses database table names for **where** and association names for **joins**, **includes** and **eager_load**.

```
Request.joins(job: :quote).where(jobs: {quotes: {attachment_updated_at: nil}}).pluck(:id)
```

Another tip: do not forget to add **distinct** to avoid *duplicate* requests.

```
Request.joins(job: :quote).where(jobs: {quotes: {attachment_updated_at: nil}}).distinct.pluck(:id)
```

Comment: Just a small comment to say that it uses table alias names if one is present, hence `Book.joins(work: :books).where(books: {id: 23})` and `Book.joins(work: :books).where(books_works: {id: 23})` are both valid, as the join from books to works and back to books again causes one of the references to the books table to be aliased to `books_works`, with a FROM clause of `FROM "books" INNER JOIN "works" ON "works"."id" = "books"."work_id" INNER JOIN "books" "books_works"`